# Question regarding career in Mathematics

Tags: career-path, mathematics

I apologize if this is not the correct place to ask such a question. This is my first time using Stack Exchange. Please feel free to point me to another site if this is not the correct place to ask this :)

I just completed my undergraduate degree in Mathematics and Applied Mathematics. The reason I chose these two majors is purely because I have a passion for maths and honestly enjoyed every moment of it. I have no regrets in choosing them as my majors.

Now that I am done with undergraduate, it is time for me to decide what I want to do next year. In my country, after finishing a undergraduate degree, you can do one year Honours degree after which you do Masters and PhD.

I can not see myself doing anything other than working with mathematics for the rest of my life. I would love to pursue postgraduate studies in (Pure) mathematics and work as a researcher and lecturer. My lecturers have pointed out to me that I have potential in mathematics, however, I do not know if I am good enough to make it "out there" at other universities (since I do not think I want to stay in my current country for my Masters and PhD).

My Pure mathematics throughout undergraduate used to be in the range of 69% - 85 % in first two years of undergrad, however, in my final year of undergrad (when we started courses such as Advanced Real Analysis, Topology, Abstract Algebra, Complex Analysis, Group/Ring Theory etc) my marks jumped greatly into the 90% since I really loved the more "abstract" work.

My question is basically - do you think I will be fine (and by that I mean "good enough") in order to pursue a career in mathematics academic and research? Will my more moderate marks of my first two years count against me greatly, or will my final year marks be a decent indication that I am competent enough to further my studies in Mathematics and succeed in an academic position? And most of all, what will it take for me to succeed and make this dream of mine a reality. Any help and advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question is too broad to be answerable. Moreover, knowing only your grades, it is impossible for strangers on the internet to assess your potential as a math researcher.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pursue a mathematics career, the first step is to apply to PhD programs. Once you have been accepted into a PhD program, your undergraduate grades no longer matter - no one will ever look at them again. People only care about your most recent activity.

As far as I can tell, you are asking two questions: (i) Are my grades good enough to get into a good PhD program? (ii) Based on my grades, will I be successful as a mathematician?

(i) The biggest factor in terms of getting into a good PhD program is your recommendation letters. Grades are not the deciding factor. It sounds like your grades are good enough that they won't count against you. So you should really ask your professors for career advice, as they have a better sense of your abilities and they will be writing letters for you. i.e. you should ask them for suggestions about where/how to apply for PhD programs.

(ii) It's very difficult to predict how well you will do based on what you did as an undergraduate. There are people who are amazing as undergraduates and then struggle as researchers and also people who are not exceptional as undergraduates and then become amazing researchers. Of course there is a strong correlation between how well you do as an undergraduate and how well you do as a researcher, but it is not perfect. There is no way to know for sure.

The only way to find out for sure is to try!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer :). I really appreciate it :)